# past form question

Tags: meaning

> In the last 1 month, how many times did you go to a restaurant
>   and **spent** more than $150 on yourself and/or others?

Does it mean:

(How many times did you go to a restaurant) and (how many times did you spend more than $150 on yourself and/or others)?

or

How many times did you (go to a restaurant and spend more than $150 on yourself and/or others)?

I don't understand why "spent" is used. Is it correct to use "spend"?

Comment: *Spent* is not correct. It looks like a simple typo to me.

Answer (score 1):

*Spend* is correct. As Jason Bassford said in a comment, it is probably a mistake. Either they wrote *t* instead of *d* by accident, or they mixed up tenses due to sloppy editing.